# How to update specific key/values in object efficiently using a sort-type function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, keyvaluepair

I am creating a JavaScript game of tic-tac-toe and trying to make it smart enough to make wise moves based on the strategy outlined in Wikipedia article. I.E., if there is a row or column that has two Xs or two Os in it, take the empty spot. So, given a row or column of key value pairs, let's say the values might be:
obj {
  key1: "X",
  key2: "",
  key3: "X",
}

I have been working on a way to do this for a while, and am curious if there are ways to do this other than a series of loops. My first attempt was to try to sort the items alphabetically so I could isolate the blank value: var = "","X","X"

In this case I can easily call the first item and update it, but I cant reverse it to what it was and update it in its original position in the object. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this in a way that isn't creating a lot of wasteful code. Would it perhaps be better to separate into multiple loops? One to isolate the rows and columns (there are 8 of them) that have one blank spot?

Another idea I had is to give each value in the grid a value of 1, and then look through the grid and if a row is equal to 3 (create var that joins them and uses the .eval() method), then make each item equal to 1, hence updating the blank spot to 1 and updated the other two spots that are already 1.

I tried to be as specific as possible but I am not great at explaining this particular problem, I admit.

Here is a JS fiddle I made:
https://jsfiddle.net/1hup5195/

Here is some of my script for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
var playerTurn = true;
var buttonStatus = "allowclick"; // Change to inactive once game starts
var player = "";
var machine = "";
var test = "";
var emptyObj = {1: "", 2: "", 3: "",
                4: "", 5: "", 6: "",
                7: "", 8: "", 9: ""};
var gridObj = {1: "", 2: "", 3: "",
               4: "", 5: "", 6: "",
               7: "", 8: "", 9: ""};
var winningObj = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9], [1,5,9], [3,5,7]];




// Check if player is holding a corner
function machineFunction() {
    // Loop through winningObj and check if there are rows/columns with 2/3 taken
    // for(i = 0; i < winningObj.length; i++) {
        var i = 3;
        var alpha = winningObj[i][0];
        var bravo = winningObj[i][1];
        var charlie = winningObj[i][2];
        console.log(alpha);
        console.log(bravo);
        console.log(charlie);
        // After defining alpha/bravo/charlie, fire the fxn
        testFxn(alpha, bravo, charlie);
        // This is my function to sort the 3 different spots within the grid
        function testFxn(a,b,c) {
            // Test would be equal to ["", "X", "X"] or something similar
            var test = [gridObj[a], gridObj[b], gridObj[c]].sort();
            console.log(test);
            console.log(gridObj);
            // If 2/3 spots taken by either X or O, take this spot
            if (test[0] === "" && test[1] === "X" && test[2] === "X") {
                console.log("#" + alpha + "")
                $('#' + alpha + '').html(machine);
                gridObj[alpha] = machine;
                console.log(gridObj);
                $(this).html(machine); // Sends player over to html
                gridObj[this.id] = machine; // Update gridObj object
                playerTurn = true;
            }
            if (test[0] === "" && test[1] === "O" && test[2] === "O") {
                // How do I get the ID I need??
                $('#' + test[0] + '').html(machine);
                playerTurn = true;
            }
        };
```

Comment: This is the link for the Fiddle, I don't think the previous one works. (https://jsfiddle.net/1hup5195/#&togetherjs=i67M4LaRnw)

Answer (score 0):

You can do sth like this ( using some to iterate... ):

```
var rows = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9], [1,5,9], [3,5,7]];
var gridObj = {1: "", 2: "", 3: "",
           4: "", 5: "", 6: "",
           7: "", 8: "", 9: ""};

rows.some(function(row){//iterate over all rows
   var values=row.map(key=>gridObj[key]);//get the rows values
   if(values.filter(el=>el==="X").length===2){//check if there are two Xses
      gridObj[rows[values.indexOf("")]]="O";//get the field id and add O to the blank field
      return true;//stop iterating the rows
   }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/miriwuhuce/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment, but I can't. So here is my comment as answer...

If you make an object of each "field", you can reference it in different arrays. So you can do an array.copy, sort that one and then change the value in the object.

This will also set the value in the other arrays holding the same objects.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a great function called `map` and can be used on arrays. [Here is documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control).

What map does is provide a callback that will perform some defined function on each element in an array, (possibly checking winning states against the current state), and returning a new array with those changed, or unchanged, values. For example, you can have an array of winning states like you do now, and do

```
var winner = winningObj.map((item) => {  // ()=>{} is ES6 syntax. Same as function(){}
    var token = {}
    if currentState[item[0]] != empty
        token.1st = X

    if currentState[item[1]] != empty
        token.2nd = X
    if currentState[item[2]] != empty
        token.3rd = X

    if all tokens are X
        return X        // winner!
    else if all tokens are O
        return O      // check the other winning conditions, or keep playing
    else
        return false
);

if winner.containsValue(X)
    X wins
else if winner.containsValue(O)
    O wins
else
    keep playing
```

I know this doesn't really answer your question in terms of better efficiency, but this way you can avoid having to write out any loops and let `map()` do all the work for you.